# Find Function with RichTextBox with Labels

Tags: richtextbox

What I'm trying to do is to make it where the user can type in a textbox and then click on a button and it will search the richtextbox for what they are looking for and if it found something it will change the label.
   (Instances) 
    `
    Button = btn_Search

```
Textbox = InputBox

RichTextBox = rtb

Label = Results`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method, to find any Text inside your `RichTextBox`.

```
public int FindMyText(string searchText, int searchStart, int searchEnd)
{
    // Initialize the return value to false by default.
    int returnValue = -1;

    // Ensure that a search string and a valid starting point are specified.
    if (searchText.Length > 0 && searchStart >= 0) 
    {
        // Ensure that a valid ending value is provided.
        if (searchEnd > searchStart || searchEnd == -1)
        {    
            // Obtain the location of the search string in richTextBox1.
            int indexToText = richTextBox1.Find(searchText, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
            // Determine whether the text was found in richTextBox1.
            if(indexToText >= 0)
            {
                // Return the index to the specified search text.
                returnValue = indexToText;
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

call this method like this:

```
var res= FindMyText("hello",0. richTextBox1.Text.Length);
```

now if `res>-1`, that means positive match, then you can set your labels i.e.

```
if(res>-1){
        lbl1.Text = "hello found";
}
```

source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8683fec1-f269-45a3-9dd7-6e73e6be464f/)

Answer (score 0):

Another method of searching text that is far more clean is as below,but first you need to add 
**System.Text.RegularExpressions** namespace to your project;

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength >= 1)
        {
            string word = textBox1.Text;//The text you want to search.
            Regex searchterm = new Regex(word);//A Regular Expression is most efficient way of working with text.
            MatchCollection matches = searchterm.Matches(richTextBox1.Text);
            if (matches.Count >= 1)
            { 
                Results=matches.Count.ToString();//Your label to display match instances.
                richTextBox1.SelectAll();
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
                richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
                    richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should do the job,furthermore if you want to specify additional search options,replace the line with Regex searchterm with anyone below,

**Case Insensitive**

> Regex searchterm = new Regex(word,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

**Whole Word Search**

> Regex searchterm = new Regex(@"\b"+word+"\b");

**Case Insensitive and Whole Word Search**

> Regex searchterm = new Regex(@"\b"+word+"\b",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

and one more thing,**Regex** searches are case-sensitive by default.